# Как сохранить список и занести его обратно в программу после поворота?

Tags: java, android

Интересует такой вопрос, возможно ли сделать, чтобы список (List) мог бы сохраняться при повороте телефона(вертикально и горизонтально). То есть я делаю какие либо изменения в классе и хочу, чтобы при повороте у меня были также показан измененный список. Но когда я поворачиваю телефон, то список снова становится стандартным(нету изменений, которые были внесены до поворота). Кто то может знает как это реализовать?

Comment: Да, можно. Полно примеров в интернете, нужно только взять и поискать.

Comment: @Эникейщик а вы можете подсказать. Я пару нашел за это время. Написал их но итогом оказалось то что у меня приложение закрывалась

Answer (score 1, accepted):

конечно можно.
есть 3 пути:

1. классика для новичков "Запрет пересоздания экрана при повороте".
   Активити / Фрагмент имеют свой жизненный цикл. при повороте экрана они уничтожаются и создаются заново. при этом можно создать 2 разных разметки и они будут переключаться.
   можно запретить пересоздание Активити указава в Манифесте для этой активити

`<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"> <intent-filter>`

хранить ваш массив нужно будет как поле в самого Активити.
но если вы захотите иметь 2 разных разметки - вы обломаетесь.

2. использование олдскульного `onSaveInstancestate`
   идея такая, что в onPause вы сохраняете данные, а в onResume их вытаскиваете.
   старая школа, но в ней куча минусов:

- все это надо делать своими руками
- могу ошибаться, но он вроде ограничен по размерам в 500кб (как и bundle) (но я могу ошибаться!)

3. современное кашерное и отличное решение! ViewModel!
   класс, в котором вы храните ваши данные и владельцом которого является Активити / Фрагмент. ViewModel под капотом уманя и сама понимает что вы делаете "переворот экрана или полное закрытие?".
   и сама сохранит данные при перевороте экрана.
   все, что вам надо сделать - создать новый класс для вашего активити / фрагмента, отнаследоваться от ViewModel, вызывать правильно этот класс в вашем экране. готово!

Comment: Интересно. Про последние я не знал. Но вот какое дело. Я первый ваш способ пробовал и он мне не подошел. Третий впервые вижу так что изучу. Но в моем случае нужен второй способ, так как у меня две разметки. Можете подсказать что использовать для сохранения в Pause

Comment: первый способ пишется для каждой активити отдельно. второй - старье. 3ий - современный и его лучше всего использовать (хотя 3ий под капотом использует как раз 2ой)

Comment: Просто я не понимаю как сохранить. Для boolean или int я знаю как это сделать. Но вот как для List или массива я не знаю.

Comment: @FarKane лучше используйте 3ий, учитесь сразу делать на современных, хороших и удобных решениях.

Comment: я по пробую объязательно третий способ. Но мне по заданию надо делать из книги. А там используется старый способ. Просто я думал может есть что то типа putInt  или getInt, ток для List(я знаю что это для типа данных)

Comment: @FarKane сугубо мое личное мнение, но книги по Андроиду, система которого меняется каждый код и что-то постоянно устаревает, а на смену приходит более удобное и продуманное решение, не стоит читать. а что касается вашего вопроса "как массивы сохранить?", то все, АБСОЛЮТНО ВСЕ, можно десереализовать в строку, сохранить, а потом вытащить как строку и превратить обратно в массив объектов.

Comment: а вот это вы интересное решение предложили сейчас. Ток вопрос в джаве есть  такое?

Comment: @FarKane конечно! можно это сделать самому руками, наследуясь либо от Serializable либо от Parcelable. а можно просто подключить библиотеку Gson (которая нужна и для работы с БД и для сетевых запросов) и сделать это в 1 строку кода

Comment: @FarKane когда дойдете до вопроса "как передать данные из одной Активити / Фрагмента в другой" вы снова столкнетесь с этим вопросом и варианты решения - такие же.

Comment: @FarKane а вот если будете использовать ViewModel, то вопрос "передачи данных между Фрагментами " может быть решен автоматически!))

Comment: можно вам показать мой код и вы подсказали по нему, а то я уже не понимаю что делаю не так. Я пробовал ваш второй предложенный способ, но у меня вышло, что так же выводит список. Если да, то буду вам благодарен.

Comment: @FarKane напишите в телеграм punk_bass